# Remove a line with a specific pattern in one field

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

Below is my input file, `input.txt`:

`Value Value1  value2` 
`5        1       2` 
`1        4       3` 
`2        1       5.5` 
`0        0       0` 
`4        1       0`

I need to search the value(5.5) in the 3rd column, if found i need to remove the row entirely.

And i need the output like below, `output.txt`:

`Value Value1  value2` 
`5        1       2` 
`1        4       3` 
`0        0       0` 
`4        1       0`

i have tried awk command to remove the row, but I'm stuck with the below part(???). Don't to how to remove the row entire row from awk command. please suggest way to achieve this. Thanks! 
`awk -F"\t" '{if($3==5.5) ??? }'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want exclude all lines with 3rd column's value `5.5` then:

```
awk '$3!=5.5' filename
```

Comment: Thanks for resposne. `awk '$3!=5.5' filename` this command will work without a if condition, sorry if it's too basic. Right now i dont have a pc to test, give a try later.

Comment: Yes. awk will print all lines by default. So the condition is to exclude the lines whose 3rd column has value `5.5`.

Answer (score 4):

GNU safer sed

```
sed -r '/\s*(\S+\s+){2}5.5/d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane 'next if($F[2]=~/5.5/);print' your_file
```

if the third column has 5.5 then that row will be removed.
But if the third column is 5.52 or 15.53, then with the above command they will be removed.
So if you want to only remove the row if it has 5.5 exact match then use below:

```
perl -lane 'next if($F[2]=~/\b5.5\b/);print' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
Value Value1 value2 
5 1 2 
1 4 3 
2 1 5.51 
2 1 5.5 
0 0 0 
4 1 0
>
```

With the first command:

```
> perl -lane 'next if($F[2]=~/5.5/);print' temp
Value Value1 value2 
5 1 2 
1 4 3 
0 0 0 
4 1 0
>
```

With the second command:

```
> perl -lane 'next if($F[2]=~/\b5.5\b/);print' temp
Value Value1 value2 
5 1 2 
1 4 3 
2 1 5.51 
0 0 0 
4 1 0
>
```

Comment: I'd have preferred `unless`: `print unless($F[2]=~/5.5/);`.  Seems more readable.  YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for response, i used awk for solving this.

Comment: There's a bug in this. The match should be `$F[2]=~/5\.5/`. But I can't help wondering why you didn't use `$F[2] eq '5.5'`.